# How can I programmatically change my windows domain password?

Tags: windows, dns, passwords

In other words, how to change my password without going through the "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> -> **Change Password**" interface.

By programmatically I mean via a command-line tool, C# via a .NET library, COM-invocation via Python, ... Whatever doesn't involve any manual steps, really.

The `NET USER` command is ineligible, as it requires me to run with domain administrator privileges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [DirectoryEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry?view=netframework-4.7.2) class to get and update the active directory entry for the user.

http://linuxonly.nl/docs/21/43_Circumvent_password_expiry_in_Windows.html

Comment: Exactly my use case too. :) Thanks!

Comment: The code in that article looks like it might answer the question, but I disagree with the actual article since it doesn't mention that it would only work on a badly managed system where *Minimum Password Age* hasn't been set.

Comment: @ho1 Thanks. I changed the article to include a note on the minimum password age.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Ah, didn't realise it was your article.

Comment: The "Minimum Password Age" setting is utterly horribly STUPID, since it means you will be unable to change your password if it is compromised. -- Example: You changed your password this morning, then accidentally type your password in the user field while holding a presentation in front of 50 people.

Comment: @Deestan I think the reasoning for the "minimum password age" is to prevent reuse of passwords by changing the password multiple times so that it can eventually be changed back to the original password.  This is exactly what the code in the answer does.  The problem could be solved by storing all previous passwords, but that method has other disadvantages.  If a password is compromised within the "minimum password age", a domain admin can allow (require) it to be changed again.

Comment: +1 Nice link.  I was able to use it to create an application that changes the password once rather than multiple times.  See my answer for the code.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a modified version of the code Sjoerd provided that changes the password once rather than cycling through multiple password changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ChangePassword
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Domain = Environment.UserDomainName;
            string User = Environment.UserName;

            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: ChangePassword OldPassword NewPassword [User]");
                System.Console.WriteLine("       -The domain is " + Domain + ".");
                System.Console.WriteLine("       -The user is " + User + " unless it is specified.");
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            string OldPassword = args[0];
            string NewPassword = args[1];
            if (args.Length == 3)
                User = args[2];

            DirectoryEntry entry = null;
            try {
                entry = new DirectoryEntry(@"WinNT://" + Domain + "/" + User + ",User");
            }
            catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Domain/User failed due to:");
                Exception cause = e.InnerException;
                System.Console.WriteLine(cause.Message);
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            try {
                entry.Invoke("ChangePassword", OldPassword, NewPassword);
            }
            catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Password change failed due to:");
                Exception cause = e.InnerException;
                System.Console.WriteLine(cause.Message);
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("Ok.");
        }
    }
}
```